# CanJS - IE8 Error "'this.constructor._bubble' is null or not an object" (can.Map)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, canjs

maybe have someone the same problem with can JS at the past time.

We have the problem ('this.constructor._bubble' is null or not an object') only in IE8, but we can't locate the problem.

Maybe have someone a short advice for me.
Thank you!